# Graphics glitches and freezes - can anyone make sense of this kernel panic?

Tags: kernel-panic

I had problems with [weird graphical glitches](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88734/2011-macbook-pro-gpu-dying#comment104012_88734) on my 2011 Macbook Pro. On service, they concluded it was a software issue, not a hardware one. I formatted my SSD and reinstalled Lion (since this is what the recovery tool gave me, even though I had Mountain Lion before). It worked for a week, but now the problems are recurring again. I managed to get a kernel panic log this time. Can anyone make sense of it?

The glitches makes me unable to boot sometimes, even to my Windows partition, until I reset PRAM. I'm really worried that this means that it is indeed a hardware problem.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  198282 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    ACA74E6B-8C24-4F61-9851-1FD7A6E7FBB0

Mon Jun 10 20:07:07 2013
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80002b955c): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff80008bfaa0, lock owner thread=0xffffff80139819c0, current_thread: 0xffffff801406dfc0, lock owner active on CPU 0x3, current owner: 0xffffff80139819c0"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:376
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f109b5e0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80f109b660 : 0xffffff80002b955c 
0xffffff80f109b6a0 : 0xffffff80002ac494 
0xffffff80f109b7c0 : 0xffffff8000269a3a 
0xffffff80f109b870 : 0xffffff8000269e98 
0xffffff80f109b8e0 : 0xffffff800026dcf3 
0xffffff80f109b9a0 : 0xffffff8000276135 
0xffffff80f109bb00 : 0xffffff80002763b8 
0xffffff80f109bb20 : 0xffffff800026ea0b 
0xffffff80f109bb90 : 0xffffff80005f7be4 
0xffffff80f109bbc0 : 0xffffff80005f76d9 
0xffffff80f109bbf0 : 0xffffff80005f7736 
0xffffff80f109bc10 : 0xffffff80005f75b0 
0xffffff80f109bc40 : 0xffffff80005f5bb9 
0xffffff80f109bc90 : 0xffffff80005e7a26 
0xffffff80f109bce0 : 0xffffff80005e5044 
0xffffff80f109bd10 : 0xffffff80005e7a26 
0xffffff80f109bd60 : 0xffffff80005e5044 
0xffffff80f109bd90 : 0xffffff80005e7a26 
0xffffff80f109bde0 : 0xffffff8000620127 
0xffffff80f109be00 : 0xffffff80006227bb 
0xffffff80f109be10 : 0xffffff8000654d7b 
0xffffff80f109be50 : 0xffffff800029d8a5 
0xffffff80f109be80 : 0xffffff8000223096 
0xffffff80f109beb0 : 0xffffff80002148a9 
0xffffff80f109bf10 : 0xffffff800021bbd8 
0xffffff80f109bf70 : 0xffffff80002aef10 
0xffffff80f109bfb0 : 0xffffff80002daec3 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: UserEventAgent

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 19697272187
last loaded kext at 10102052345: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard  160.7 (addr 0xffffff7f81eb7000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.Logitech.Unifying.HID Driver    1.3.0
com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.10.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000    7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   561.7.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   160.7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller    7.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  13
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
System Profile:
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series, 512,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0246, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called Apple, asked for a complaint (EU customers can have it up to 3 years after purchase). They gave me a case ID but told me to go to the local service and let them handle it.

This time, they concluded that the HDD/SSD bracket/cable (don't know the correct English term for this) was loose. After testing with a different one, they concluded that this was the problem. The cause was probably due to not using ESD protection when installing the new RAM or SSD. I will get it back tomorrow, and hopefully this is the cause and not a faulty logic board.

EDIT: It seems like this didn't solve anything, but it now beeps three times when crashing and on boot, which indicates faulty memory. Ordered new, now waiting...